# Install Linux on external hard disk partition

Tags: windows, macos, boot, arch-linux

I am not an expert in Linux stuff, but I managed to install the live image of Apricity OS in a partition of my external 2 TB Hard Disk. After that, I successfully installed the full OS in another partition of the same HD.

Until here, everything fine. The problem now is about "portability" of the OS, since with all Mac computer, I can choose which partition boot by pressing Alt + Power (and it will appear my Live partition and the Os one).

The problem is in non Mac computer. I tried to change the BIOS boot order putting the USB as first one, but when I start the PC I get

> No Operating System Found

What can I do to solve the problem?

In addition, I would also like to know how to rename my OS, since when I choose the partition to boot I always see "EFI boot".

Comment: Are you trying to effectively hot swap OS installs between different hardware? I would advise against this as it could get very messy with drivers.

Comment: I think you may have installed the bootloader on the fixed/internal hard drive of your Mac instead of the external one. Just boot into your external hard drive on your machine and install the bootloader (only the bootloader not the whole os) onto the external drive.

Comment: @adampski yes what I want is to boot my Linux os installed in my external hd in any machine. I know that it could be messy with drivers, but I want to try anyway, at least succesfullying booting the os

Comment: @vishalbiswas I did not install the bootloader (I think). I only installed the live and then the full OS. Anyway I am sure I did not install anything on my mac. To choose the startup disk, I use the pre defined mac combination alt + power when the computer is  off

Comment: The bootloader is installed automatically (most times) as the last step of installation from a live environment. It may also be possible that your installation is EFI only and the other computer doesn't support it or has it disabled.

Comment: What does it mean my installation is EFI only? I knew the efi partition is created only when the Mac formats an hard disk

Answer (score 0):

During installation you have to make sure the boot device is set to the external drive, not a partition or a local drive.

This will enable it to boot pretty much anywhere :)

To do this in Apricity follow this simple guide:

- Start installing the system as usual.
- At the "Partitions step" look at the bottom of the installer window and make sure you selected the external hard drive.
- Finish installing the system as usual.